# Pharo ZnServer printOn: Transcript

Tags: pharo

Did this: `ZnServer printOn: Transcript.`

No longer need this on transcript and would like to stop the server from printing on it now.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know the class and method where `printOn:` message is sent? Or are you asking how to find them?

Comment: I cant actually remember, I put the command in playground and wiped it. Transcript just keeps getting ZnServer output that eventually gives me a stderr not available error on my server.. Is there any way to halt all messages to transcript?

Comment: Insert `self halt` in `ThreadSafeTranscript >> nextPut:` and when the debugger opens take a look to the message stack to understand where is the sender.

Comment: That worked! Was `ZnLogToTranscript` evaluated `self stopLoggingToTranscript.` to solve issue.